# How should major API version propagate to Terraform provider?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

context: we're developing a new TF Provider

Let's say there're 2 resources `foo` and `bar` in TF provider that are based on:

- `api/aaa/v1/foos`
- `api/bbb/v4/bars`

How shall one handle major API version upgrades (for example, `api/aaa/v2/foos`)? I can see 2 options:

1. Add versions to resource names like `foo_v1` and `bar_v4` to be super clear about the underlying version (similar to what k8s TF Provider [does](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/service_v1)). And then add new `foo_v2` resource.
2. Do not include versions in resource names and any time API version is bumped for a specific API group - release a new major version the TF provider and document any differences in default behaviors. The downside of this approach -- we might bump TF version too often (for every API group update).

Comment: Is the API version update specific to all endpoints, or to only a subset of the endpoints?

Comment: Only to a subset. For example, resource1 -> endpoint1 (aaa/v2 API group), resource2 -> endpoint2 (bbb/v1 API group), there could be multiple resources (resource3 -> endpoint3, resource4 -> endpoint4) under the same (ccc/v5 API group)

Comment: updated endpoint the questions to make it more clear: `api/v1/aaa/foos` -> `api/aaa/v1/foos`

Comment: @MattSchuchard could you elaborate about potential headaches?

Comment: and why k8s TF provider chose that route, for example (are there any interesting specific about that API: api version is specific for all endpoints)?

Comment: Sorry typo; should be: Then you probably do not want to correlate that with a new major version of the provider, because that could potentially become a headache for you in multiple ways.